# Truetype font not displaying on one client workstation with Citrix Xenapp

Tags: printing, fonts, citrix

I have a truetype barcode font that prints in a ssrs report from a third party application which runs through citrix xen app.  On every single other client machine (8 different machines) it prints properly, but on a single client computer running windows xp (not the only windows xp machine) the font does not display, instead it defaults to numbers.   I have verified the font is installed on the client machine.  Preview on client is NOT checked, but EMF viewer comes up when I attempt to print.